# vim, nano or other in terminal editor for python & git?

Tags: python, git, vim, terminal, nano

What in terminal editor would you recommend using/learning for python, git & remote terminal sessions over ssh? New to vim and nano. I know how to exit and save/exit vim and that's about it.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Asking for software recommendations or references is *specifically* listed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend vim for learning python. You can configure vim by *Plug* or *VimAwesome*.